# removing rows from dataframe if column value condition is met

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops, rows

```
stables=["usdt","usdc","tusd"]
```

my dataframe called "df" looks like this (actual dataframe has hundreds of rows):

```
               pairs           apy  network            pool name
0        [eth, wbtc]  1.150699e+01   cometh      cometh-eth-wbtc
1        [usdt, usdc]  1.814333e+01  cometh      cometh-usdt-usdc
2     [must, pickle]  2.175891e+01   cometh      cometh-must-pickle
3        [usdt, eth]  1.237610e+02   cometh      cometh-usdt-eth
4       [eth, matic]  2.181968e+01   cometh      cometh-eth-matic
```

the 'pairs' column has lists of items. Going row by row, I want to remove the whole row if any of the items in the 'pairs' column list is not included in the 'stables' list provided above.

in this case only the second row (indexed 1) would stay in the dataframe as both items are in the 'stables' list provided above.

any help is welcome.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `pairs` column actually contains list of strings, you could explode that column, use `isin` to test which elements are members of the `stables` list, ang then use a `groupby` `agg` `np.all` to test if all elements of an intial row are members of `stables`:

```
temp = df.explode('pairs')
temp['keep'] = temp['pairs'].isin(stables)
temp = temp.groupby(level=0)['keep'].agg(np.all)

to_keep = df[temp]
```

Comment: yes! that worked perffectly! thanks a lot Serge Ballesta